# Does Content Syndication to a Microblogging websites help in Link building?

Tags: blog, canonical-url, link-building, rel-canonical, syndication

Let say I've a blog and a `medium.com` account. Now, I use an API and syndicate all my blog content to `medium.com` with `rel=canonical` tag.

Does this helps in Brand Reputation Building? 
Does this helps in Link building or it passes any links to the original blog because it is using `rel=canonical`.

Answer (score 2):

No it won't and this strategy died or no longer effective long time ago. It will only create more duplicated copy of the content which is obviously spam related.

And it's like you are chopping your overall content and spread them all over the web which offers no value to the readers it will reach.

Creating unique and fresh content are just one of the main and challenging fields of modern SEO

Answer (score 1):

For the providing site, syndication increases exposure. That's a fact.

This generates new traffic for the transmitting sitemaking syndication an easy and relatively cheap, or even free, form of advertisement.

As search engine optimization has become an increasingly important topic among website owners and online marketers, content syndication has become a highly effective strategy for link building.

Links embedded within the syndicated content are typically optimized around anchor terms that will point an optimized link back to the website that the content author is trying to promote. These links tell the algorithms of the search engines that the website being linked to is an authority for the keyword that is being used as the anchor text.

Comment: Man if somebody is already posted a Content X on his blog and then syndicated the same content on Medium type website with the same content ? Does that really helps ? Because why would somebody will click on the read more button when all the information is already available over there.
Next, you're talking about link building like putting links on anchor words and I'm talking about syndication for that particular blog post.